# Replicate range of numbers bar those within a certain range

Tags: excel

I have a big sheet spreadsheet of percentages, and I want to replicate that in another sheet, but where the original percentages are less than (say) 5%, I would like them to become 5% in the new sheet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have it calculating the formula for 5% do the following:

```
=if(your formula, <=.05,.05,your formula)
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to be of assistance, just so you know that equation reads....  If the result of your formula is less than or equal to 5%, then display 5%, otherwise, display the result of your formula.

Comment: To avoid executing *your formuala* twice, use `=MAX(your formuala, 5%)`